# Retrieve custom field using describeSObject in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, salesforce, integration, force.com

I integrated salesforce with .Net using SOAP API. I like to retrieve the field details from salesforce.

I am using describeSObjectresult and describeSObject to achieve this.But,it retrieves both(standard & custom) field information from salesforce.

I like to retrieve only custom field from salesforce.

Is it possible.

Thanks,
Rajeshkumar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a custom (or isCustom depending on how your soap tool maps it into your language) flag on the field, that you can use to filter out standard fields. No need to grunge around with the field name.

Comment: I filtered the custom field like I mentioned in my own answer below. Thanks for your thought.

Answer (score -1):

The custom fields can be retrieved by, Hence custom fields in salesforce ends with "__c" so we can easily identify it.

```
                `for (int i = 0; i < _fields.Length; i++)
               {     Field _fieldproperty = _fields[i];

                      if (_fieldproperty.name.EndsWith("__c"))   { 
                       string Labelname = _fieldproperty.label; } }
```